# Endless Scrolling for RecyclerView and making new api call to show fresh data

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, lazy-loading, retrofit

I already created `endlessScrollListener` for my `RecyclerView`. Inside my `onLoadMore` method I'm making a new api call each time I'm at the bottom of the page. 
I need to give my `apiCall` method new parameters for a new api call to get fresh data. I start api call with page 1, and 30 - for items count. Next api call should have 2,30, next 3,30 and so on. 
I'm thinking to do for loop. But could anyone suggest a nicer way?

```
public void makeApiCall(int pageNumber, int pageSize) {

    ApiCall.ApiCallRx apiCall = ApiCall.createRx();

    Observable<Response<ApiObject>> observable =
            apiCall.apiItems(ApiKey.apiKey, pageNumber, pageSize);

    observable.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).
            subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).
            observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).
            subscribe(new Subscriber<Response<ApiObject>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "Call Failed"+ e.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Response<ApiObject> apiResponse) {
                    callSuccess(apiResponse);
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "Call Success");

                }
            });
}

private void callSuccess(Response<ApiObject> apiResponse) {

    apiItems = apiResponse.body().getProducts();
    objectAdapter = new ObjectAdapter(apiItems);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(objectAdapter);
}

private void setScrollListener(){

    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(linearLayoutManager) {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {

         makeApiCall(2,30);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I am using `RecyclerView` like you . And its working so good. Do you have problems in this way ?

Comment: no problems with the recycler view. but scroll listener doesn't work the way i want.

Comment: okey. what you want , my recyclerview triggerrs loadmore method when i am going to bottom. Everytime !

Comment: do you use onScrollListener? Where do you load your data from? Do you make api call?

Answer (score 0):

You only need your last page number to know which page to fetch next. 
Assuming the page number passed to onLoadMore is the last page number, when onLoadMore is called just increment it by one and fetch the next page.
You should also maintain if a page request is ongoing. If a request if ongoing you should not initiate another request. Something like this

```
if (!requestInProgress){
  pageNumber += 1;
  requestInProgress = true;
  makeApiCall(pageNumber)
}
```

And once api request is done you set requestInProgress to false. You can also maintain a flag to indicate whether all the pages have been fetched or not and use it to decide whether to make a request.

Answer (score 0):

You might wana add notifyDataSetChanged(); in you call success method.

Below code snippet will allow you to detect when the view has reached its end

```
recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener(){
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int      visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)
   {
    if(firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount >= totalItemCount){
        // End has been reached
    }
}
```

and make sureyou make a logic to make api call once since this will call api multiple times since you are at the endof list.. Make a global variable and set it in onScroll method and reset it in onSuccess() so u can prevent multiple api calls.

> If you want to track your page numbers one of the way is to use
>   [sharedprefrences](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) to store your last page key in onSucess method
>   and read it in your onScroll method and then increment it by 1 and
>   call the api.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

For your comment yes i am using scroll listener,simply you can follow this guide [load-more-recyclerview-bottom-progressbar](https://codentrick.com/load-more-recyclerview-bottom-progressbar/):

First of all your `RecyclerView.Adapter` must be like :

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter{

ArrayList<YourModel> models;
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private OnLoadMoreListener mOnLoadMoreListener;
private boolean isLoading;
private int visibleThreshold = 5;
private int lastVisibleItem, totalItemCount;

public void setLoaded() {
    isLoading = false;
}


public void setOnLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener mOnLoadMoreListener) {
    this.mOnLoadMoreListener = mOnLoadMoreListener;

}

public MyAdapter(ArrayList<YourModel> models,RecyclerView recyclerview){
    this.models=models;
    this.mRecyclerView=recyclerview;

    final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();
    mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
            lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                if (!isLoading && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                    if (mOnLoadMoreListener != null) {
                        mOnLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                    }
                    isLoading = true;
                }

        }
    });

    }
}
```

Then create `OnLoadMoreListener` class :

```
public interface OnLoadMoreListener {
    void onLoadMore();
}
```

Then in your `Activity` declare and add `onScrollListener` to your Adapter :

```
MyAdapter myAdapter=new MyAdapter(models,recyclerview);

myAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore() {
            if(getNEXT_PAGE()!=0) {
                if (!mIsRefreshing) {
                    //you can add null object for progress view
                    //if you dont want you can disable this 
                    needYouUsers.add(null);
                    needYouAdapter.notifyItemInserted(needYouUsers.size() - 1);
                    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
                    makeYourRequest();

                }
            }

        }
    });
```

Then you must use `setLoaded` for your adapter in method :

```
public void makeYourRequest(){

    //do your all stuff make request etc..
    //finally
     myadapter.setLoaded();
}
```